# My App name not appearing on post when photo is shared via Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to share image with FB from my app. I can do it but there is a issue. when the image shared on my FB wall, my app name not there on the post.(like instagram)
could you help me please, what is the issue?

[image: My app]

[image: Instagram Example]